# Postman: Test Assertion of different timestamps

Tags: timestamp, format, postman, delay

With postman I'm sending a POST to serverA and than a GET to serverB. Finally I want to compare the timestamps. There is a small delay in timestamps and the format is difference. How can I equilize the timestampformat?

I allready tried this:

```
    pm.expect(resBody.desiredScopeIn).to.eql(pm.environment.get("scopeInTime"));
});
```

But I keep this error:

**AssertionError: expected '2020-09-24T18:41:43Z' to deeply equal '2020-09-24T18:41:43.318Z'**

So,
I have to compare these timestamp formats:

1. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ
2. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sssZ

Comment: What did you already try? 
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There's a similar question in the Postman community: https://community.postman.com/t/test-to-check-if-timestamp-is-from-today-or-within-last-3-minutes/7851

Answer (score 0):

Have solved this with the following:
Thankyou!

```
const moment = require ("moment")
let timestampone = moment(resBody.desiredScopeIn).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
let timestamptwo = moment(pm.environment.get("scopeInTime")).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")

pm.test("timestampone is same as timestamptwo", function () {
    pm.expect(moment(timestampone).isSame(timestamptwo), "Dates do not match").to.be.true;
});
```